# Is it possible to inherit from something other than the abstract type julia?

Tags: julia

I have a function that I can't change and it expects type `ExpectedType`.

```
function some_function(some_parameter::ExpectedType)
   ....
   some implementation
   ....
end
```

I want to pass my object of type `OtherType`.

I decided to inherit `OtherType` from `ExpectedType`.

```
struct OtherType <: ExpectedType end
```

But I'm getting an error: `ERROR: invalid subtyping in definition of OtherType`

1. Is it possible to inherit from non-abst types?
2. How can I get the functionality I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It is not possible to inherit from non-abstract type.
2. What I would typically do is writing a constructor for `ExpectedType` that takes `OtherType` as argument and then call `some_function(ExpectedType(your_object))`.

Also then you could define:

```
SourceModuleName.some_function(x::OtherType) = some_function(ExpectedType(x))
```

so that you do not have to call the constructor explicitly.

Comment: the other two options for completeness are to add an `AbstractExpectedType` or to loosen the check on the function

Comment: OP indicated that "a function that I can't change and it expects type `ExpectedType`" so I assume neither of these two options are possible.

Comment: Just to resolve any ambiguity, Bogumił was talking about the two options that Oscar suggested. The concept of "a function I can't change" is a bit unusual in Julia. You can't change existing methods, but you can always add additional methods (with the same name) that are distinct in their type signatures. That is why the method(s) that Bogumił described in his answer works.